# How to inject class as new instance?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have two injectable classes.

```
@Injectable()
export class Base {
value: string;
constructor() {
    this.value = "default value";
  }
}
```

and

```
@Injectable()
export class MyClass {
constructor(private base: Base) {
    base.value = "value from MyClass";
  }
}
```

I know that injectable classes are singletons. So `MyClass` will override `value` in `Base` class for all application (I inject `Base` class not only to `MyClass`). But I need to change `value` only for `MyClass`. How to inject `Base` not as singleton? How to inject `Base` as new instance?

Comment: Do these classes *need* to be injected services? Or could they just be simple classes used by new-ing up an instance?

Comment: @DeborahK Yes, they both should be injected services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u have to provide "Base" and "MyClass" in your component like this :

```
@Component({
...
providers: [
    Base,
    MyClass
   ]
})
export class ExampleComponent { 
   ...
}
```